# Facebook Page Creation API throttle limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building an application for clients to be able to create Facebook Page in their account using my own Admin Access Token.
I have Standard Access approved for my Facebook application already.

I tried to create a few test pages using FB Graph Explorer and I succeeded.

I ran into a problem when I tried to create a page using Code in Classic ASP, it says **Have reached page creation api throttle limit**

FR- https://www.screencast.com/t/hTd4RDozov

I tried to search into the Facebook documentation to find out that when I can get out of this error, but couldn't find any response.

Are there anyone person who has got this error before? Or can someone tell when I can get rid out of this error?

Many thanks

Comment: Well the error message does not need much explaining, I think - you have created too many pages, so your app's ability to do so will be throttled, or rather blocked, for a while. I don't think any exact limits or ban times are documented anywhere - because that would give actual spammers info on how to improve their "operations". But withing reasonable business use cases you should not run into those limits often. So now what it first of all needs is some patience on your end, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks for your reply to it. I created only two pages using Graph API and few failed attempts at the same day ie. July 1st. And after that, I got blocked. But still now I am not able to create a page, still getting the same message. It's been 13 days now and god knows how much time more it would take

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently experiencing the same behavior. Talking to Facebook support they say the default limit for page creation is 2 pages per month. This number might be negotiable depending on your usecase.

Comment: Yes you are right and I think that behavior lasts for one month because I was able to create page after about one month of the error.